# Do while loop first iteration not working?

Tags: php, loops, do-while

I have a nested do while loop.  The first loop in the options inputs comes in blank with no options in the drop down menu.  All other loops after the first one work perfectly.  I am at a loss as to why the first one comes in blank and any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<h1 align="center"><a href="images.php">&lt;Back</a> - Current Photos  in <?
echo $row_titles['title']; ?></h1>
<?php if ($totalRows_photos > 0)
{
    do
    { ?>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="height:350px;overflow:hidden;"><img 
src="../contentimages/<?php echo $row_photos['filename']; ?>" class="img- 
responsive" style="max-height:225px;" /><br />
<? if ($row_photos['catid'] == 1)
        {
            echo "Commercial";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Residential";
        } ?> 
  |  <a href="images.php?id=<?php echo $row_photos['id']; ? > & amp;
        action = remove">Delete</a><br />
<form name="moveit" action=" < ? phpecho $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" 
id="moveit"><select name="folder">
  <?php
        do
        {
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_folders['id'] ?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_folders['id'], $row_photos['project_id'])))
            {
                echo "selected=\"selected\"";
            } ?>><?php echo $row_folders['title'] ?></option>
  <?php
        }
        while ($row_folders = mysql_fetch_assoc($folders));
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($folders);
        mysql_data_seek($folders, 0);
        $row_folders = mysql_fetch_assoc($folders);
?>
</select><input name="Move" type="submit" value="Move" />
<input name="hiddenField" type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="<?php echo $row_photos['id']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="moveit" />
</form></div>
  <?php
    }
    while ($row_photos = mysql_fetch_assoc($photos));
}
else
{
    echo "<h3 
align=\"center\">No photos are found!</h3>";
} ?></div>
```

Comment: Can you please make this a bit more readable?

Comment: @hudson, thanks for formatting, but please next time don't add your comments to the question, add them as comments.

Comment: Yes no problems ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the first iteration of your do while loop is returning blank values from `$row_folders` and `$row_photos` is because no value has been assigned to those variables until after the first iteration has completed (in the `while` statement)

To fix it, you can either assign the variable first, or (as is more commonly done) just use a `while` loop.

**Define the variable first:**

```
$row_folders = mysql_fetch_assoc($folders);
do
{
    // Your code here
}
while ($row_folders = mysql_fetch_assoc($folders));
```

Or **Just use a while loop**:

```
while ($row_folders = mysql_fetch_assoc($folders))
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: I tried both ways and it still is leaving the first loop blank?

Comment: Got it!  had to move the mysql_data_seek in front of the while loop and all is good.

Answer (score 1):

In a do while loop the condition is tested AFTER executing the statements within the loop.
You should change it to WHILE only moving the condition to the top to fetch the first row
notice that in the second iteration you are getting the first row becase in the first iteration execution the first row is not fetched yet.